Remove the SharePoint Configuration version number from when view the page source
How to hide the SharePoint Configuration version number from when view the page source
SiteTemplate: Team Site Classic & PWA#0 Site template has only this information showing in page view source

also below variable also showing this information
var _spPageContextInfo= siteClientTag showing SharePoint Configuration version

Hiding or modifying the DOM is generally not recommended or supported nowadays.
But try this (I cannot test it on a Server myself, sorry):
.version-class {
    display: none;
}

or Javascript code injection:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var versionElement = document.querySelector('.version-class');
    if (versionElement) {
        versionElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
});


Hi where can I implement this code? Or any other way in farm level it applicable to all sharepoint webapplication?
